# VSCode で editorGutter.modifiedBackground を設定しても反映されない

Tags: vscode

`editorGutter.modifiedBackground` とは、修正された行のガターの色を変える設定と理解して

```
"editorGutter.modifiedBackground": "#c07020",
```

このように設定してるのですが、期待していた通りに色が変わってくれません。
そもそも私の解釈が間違っているのでしょうか。

これはどのような場面の色の設定なのか教えてください。
また、修正のあった行のガターの色を変更する設定があったら教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この設定は `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` の中に書いてください。つまり、settings.json の

```js
{
    (なんとかかんとか)
}
```

に対して

```js
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorGutter.modifiedBackground": "#c07020"
    }

    (なんとかかんとか)
}
```

このように指定してください。

この設定は git などでファイルのバージョン管理をしている際に、変更された行を示すために行番号の横につく色を管理しています。以下のスクリーンショットで行番号の右側に表示されている色付きの棒をご覧ください。この青色の部分が `"editorGutter.modifiedBackground"` で指定できる部分です。

[image]

他の部分の色についてはドキュメントをご覧ください: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: ということはgitを導入していない通常のファイルでは変化しないということですか

Comment: はい、gutter の色が変化する機能はバージョン管理下で使える機能です: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_gutter-indicators 。そもそもバージョン管理がなされていない場合、どこを基準として「行の内容が変わった」などの比較を行うべきか自明でない気がします。